# jquery adding custom validator

Tags: jquery, validation

i have the following:

```
  $('#qForm').validate({
    rules: {

                answerYesNo_1: { required:true } ,

                answerYesNoText_1: { required: function(element) {
                                        return $('#answerYesNo_1').val() == 'yes';
                                       }
                , isMoney: true  }, 
                answerYesNo_2: { required:true } ,

                answerYesNoText_2: { required: function(element) {
                                        return $('#answerYesNo_2').val() == 'yes';
                                       }
                , isMoney: true  }, 
                answerYesNo_3: { required:true } ,

                answerYesNoText_3: { required: function(element) {
                                        return $('#answerYesNo_3').val() == 'yes';
                                       }
                , isMoney: true  }, 
                answerYesNo_4: { required:true } ,

                answerYesNoText_4: { required: function(element) {
                                        return $('#answerYesNo_4').val() == 'yes';
                                       }
                , isMoney: true  }, 
                answerYesNo_5: { required:true } ,

                answerYesNoText_5: { required: function(element) {
                                        return $('#answerYesNo_5').val() == 'yes';
                                       }
                , isMoney: true  }      
    },  
...


    jQuery.validator.addMethod("isMoney", function(value, element) {
    alert(/^\$?[0-9][0-9\,]*(\.\d{1,2})?$|^\$?[\.]([\d][\d]?)$/.test(value));                                          
    return /^\$?[0-9][0-9\,]*(\.\d{1,2})?$|^\$?[\.]([\d][\d]?)$/.test(value);

});
```

The problem I have is it ignores first part of the required function :

```
    return $('#answerYesNo_1').val() == 'yes'
```

Say:I pick "no" for answerYesNo_2, answerYesNo_3, answerYesNo_4, answerYesNo_5, I will get false for each one of them. If the answer is no, it shouldn't go to the isMoney validation. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("isMoney", function (value, element) {
    alert(/^\$?[0-9][0-9\,]*(\.\d{1,2})?$|^\$?[\.]([\d][\d]?)$/.test(value));
    return /^\$?[0-9][0-9\,]*(\.\d{1,2})?$|^\$?[\.]([\d][\d]?)$/.test(value);
});
$.validator.addMethod(
    'equalToParam',
    function ( value, element, param ) {
        return $.trim(value) == param;
    },
    'Do not match.'
);
$('#qForm').validate({
    rules: {
        answerYesNo_1: {
            required: true,
            equalToParam: 'yes'
        },
        answerYesNoText_1: {
            required: true,
            isMoney: true
        },
        answerYesNo_2: {
            required: true
        },
        answerYesNoText_2: {
            required: true,
            equalToParam: 'yes'
            isMoney: true
        },
        answerYesNo_3: {
            required: true
        },
        answerYesNoText_3: {
            required: true,
            equalToParam: 'yes'
            isMoney: true
        },
        answerYesNo_4: {
            required: true
        },
        answerYesNoText_4: {
            required: true,
            equalToParam: 'yes'
            isMoney: true
        },
        answerYesNo_5: {
            required: true
        },
        answerYesNoText_5: {
            required: true,
            equalToParam: 'yes'
            isMoney: true
        }
    },
```

In next time or if my piece of code isn't work make demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ pls

Comment: This doesn't work. The jsFiddle was added right after the original post in the comments section. Thx